# unable to use class or id of html element after fetching the result from ajax json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Unable to use id or class of the label, which one is fetching from php...

My Code is:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/user_list",
        data:"",
        async:false,
        success: function(rest)
        {
            $('#list').html(rest);
        }
    })
```

PHP Code is:

```
function user_list()
{
    $dir="chat_files/";
    $files1 = scandir($dir);
    $files1=array_reverse($files1);
    $count=count($files1);
    for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++)
    {
        $file_nm=explode(".",$files1[$i]);
        echo "<label id=$files1[$i] class='user'>".$file_nm[0]."</label><br>";
    }
}
```

This is not working:

```
$('.user').click(function(ace)
{
    alert('Work');
});
```

I am using codeigniter ajax send data to controller function and then show html results but in that result i am unable to use label id or class for further action... please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your elements have been added dynamically to the DOM through the AJAX call, the `click` event will not be available to these elements until you attach it. In this case, you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#list').on('click','.user', function() {
    alert('Work');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use delegation using `.on` for dynamically created element:

```
$(document).on('click','.user',function(ace)
{
  alert('Work');
});
```